# Feature files syntax highlighting is different in 1.4.1 version than older version

Tags: karate

I have the below dependency in my POM file with Karate 1.4.1 version. With this karate version, my feature files syntax are showing as shown below.

[image]

[image]

In the above image, the Given, When, Then are highlighted in Grey

To check on the older version i have used few years back, i tried with karate 0.9.6 version like below
[image]

Now, i can able to see the Syntax are properly highlighted as shown below.

[image]

Am I missing any modules in the recent 1.4.1 version? Please advice

Comment: karate has nothing to do with cucumber so you cannot expect cucumber support in intellij or eclipse to work.

Comment: I dont have cucumber in my pom. Only thing is i have the "Cucumber for Java" plugin because when i tried with the karate plugin, its asking for a license. Do i need karate plugin to run karate tests now?

Comment: the karate plugin is recommended, but optional, you will always have the option to run via the command line or via maven or gradle